# Can we deploy electron application to dll?

Tags: electron

I'm new to the electron framework. I use electron-packager to build the project. It generates a .exe file.
Is there any way to generate .dll file using electron?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do? Embedding Electron in another app? Calling a function inside your Electron app?

Comment: I want to load electron dll to C++

Comment: This might be useful: https://discuss.atom.io/t/compile-electron-into-a-library/47707/6